# Pass dynamic variables to Spark SQL queries

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to pass in variables to my Spark SQL queries but I keep getting errors. Wonder what's wrong?

```
sd='2023-01-05'
ed='2023-01-10'
spark.sql("""

SELECT id, date, SUM(cost)
FROM table
WHERE snapshot_date BETWEEN {0} AND {1}
AND id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
GROUP BY id,date
                  
""").format(sd,ed).show()
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you include the details of actual error messages that you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up the `format` method; `Dataframe` does not have a `format` method, but `String` does, so this:

```py
sd = '2023-01-05'
ed = '2023-01-10'
spark.sql("""

SELECT id, date, SUM(cost)
FROM table
WHERE snapshot_date BETWEEN {0} AND {1}
AND id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
GROUP BY id,date

""".format(sd, ed)).show()
```

should fix your issue, good luck!